# Best way to morph between waveforms

Tags: oscillator

I am making an low-frequency oscillator (LFO) that should be able to output different kinds of waveforms. 
If I, say, want to be able to create a smooth transition from a sine wave to a square wave, what would the best approach be? 
I have thought about creating several hardcoded lookup-tables and "scroll" between these, but I am worried about the transition not being smooth enough, unless there are many of these tables.

If anyone knows about the best way/usual way to solve this problem, I would be happy to hear about it.

Comment: The result of that is very simple and it's normally done with wavetables of very complex sounds, because additive synthesis of simple sines/pulses gives simple results. wavetable is a way to research it. it should be used to mix together many variables of the synth, filters, 50hz type lfo's, for physical modelling, other speeds, all into a coherent mix including the waveshape, not just the wavetable, which is for 8bit sounds and an 8 bit processing bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what we sometimes call "Vector Synthesis" and other times call "Wavetable Synthesis".  linear crossfading between equal-sized circular lookup tables usually suffices.

but make sure the waveforms are aligned.  you can circularly delay (or "rotate") one lookup table relative to the other.  choose a relative rotation so that the cross-correlation between the two waveforms is maximum.  if you somehow crossfade between a sine wave and a square wave where the fundamental of the square wave is outa phase with the sine, you'll get a glitch in the crossfade.

Comment: How do you calculate optimum rotation of the wave so they are aligned. How do you properly align a square wave with a sine wave? If all of your wave tables are single cycles will this be less of an issue?

Comment: @AranMulholland,  the answer is circular cross-correlation.  look for the $m$ that gets you the maximum $R_{xy}[m]$ where $$ R_{xy}[m] = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] y\left[(n+m)\mod(N)\right] $$  we are assuming the two wavetables, $x[n]$ and $y[n]$, are of the same length $N$ and represent exactly one period of a periodic waveform.